# SQL using SUM() with WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT/UPDATE - As I suspected, simple solution was to not group by Total Calls. Thank you for the quick replies.

```
 SELECT
    [Date],
    [Interval],
    SUM([Total Calls]) 'Total Calls'
    FROM 'My_Table' 
    WHERE [Call Type] IN ('A', 'B')
    GROUP BY [Date], [Interval], [Total Calls];
```

Okay so this is a simple snippet of what I'm doing. This works but I need numeric values from 'Call Types' A and B to be added together within the 'Total Calls' column instead of each being their own row. The SUM() doesn't seem to produce what I expected it to and I'm kinda lost on what I'm messing up here. Keep in mind that the broader scope of this code is to be able to add many more call types together than just these 2, just trying to keep this simple.

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY ..., ..., totalCalls`? Keep only the `GROUP BY date, interval` should do what you're looking for as far as I understand

Comment: The GROUP BY clause should result in each Date and Interval receiving a distinct Summary row for all call types included. If you are receiving more rows than expected, I would ensure your select and group by statements only include fields you want to group by. To Gael's point as well, aggregates ([Total Calls]) should not be included in the group by.

Can you provide an example and desired output, as well as a sample data set?

Comment: remove aggregate from group by.

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

first you don't want to group by "[Total Calls]",
second you can use grouping sets to get sum of all types as well:

```
SELECT
 [Date],
 [Interval],
 SUM([Total Calls]) 'Total Calls'
FROM 'My_Table' 
WHERE [Call Type] IN ('A', 'B')
group by grouping sets ( ([Date], [Interval]), () )
```